# How do I find my missing bitcoin on Bitcore?

Tags: coinbase.com, coinbase-transaction, bitcore

I recently tried to send bitcoin to my Bitcore wallet and it shows completed on Coinbase side, yet its not in my wallet. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

> **I recently tried to send bitcoin to my *Bitcore* wallet**

- **bitcore.cc** is a different currency (BTX) to Bitcoin (BTC). If you send BTC to a BTX wallet you may lose your money.
- **bitcore.io** is "A powerful, modular node for bitcoin and blockchain-based apps." - I believe it is primarily aimed at developers - It isn't simply a Bitcoin wallet. It does include a wallet. If you are using that, you'll need to ensure the rest of the Bitcore suite is properly configured and up and running and, if necessary, synchronised.

If you are using some other wallet - remember that transactions can take a while if you set a low fee:

- [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/13866)

Answer (score -1):

You have definitely lost money. I made a similar mistake(( I read https://cryptoine.com/biswap/ that there is no fix or refund